# show that $D_n =[e, a,a^2,...,a^n,b,ba,...,ba^{n-1}]$ forms a group

Tags: group-theory

Question : show that $D_n =[e, a,a^2,...,a^n,b,ba,...,ba^{n-1}]$ be a set of $2n$ elements. Define the product in $D_n$ by the relations $a^n =e, b^2=e$ and $ab = ba^{-1}$. Show that $D_n$ is a group.

As $D_n$ is a finite group, we can use composition table, but this is quite uncomfortable for me. Mention another ways...

Comment: For information on how to proper typeset mathematics at this site see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Shampa Das: Check out "dihedral group" on google.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*: Show that $D_n$ is the set of symmetries of a regular $n$-gon. Clearly such symmetries form a group.

Comment: D_n is the set of regular n gon, but how i will show it?? (drawing picture)???

Comment: You need to show that the symmetries $a$ and $b$ generate the group and satisfy the above relations. Then you are done. Anyway, this is done in the duplicates on this site.

Comment: Not by drawing a picture, but by using analytic geometry.

Comment: #Anyway, this is done in the duplicates on this site.Where?

Comment: For example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584538/dihedral-group-and-its-generators?rq=1). Did you search yourself already?

Comment: Yes, but not found

Comment: But, i do not understand it. You can tell me any reference book for this

Comment: You can find this in any text on group theory. For example, the lecture notes of Milne, together with a nice picture. Google "Lecture notes group theory Milne".

Comment: Here my concept clears...... Milne notes