# Show that $D_n$ is a group with composition.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

Problem: Show that $D_n$ is a group with composition, where order of $D_n$ is $2n$ and $$D_n=\{e,a,...,a^{n-1},b,ab,...,a^{n-1}b\}$$with the following relations: $a^n=e$, $b^2=e$, $ba=a^{n-1}b$.

Closure: Let $x,y\in D_n$. Then $x=a^{j_1}b^{k_1}$ and $y=a^{j_2}b^{k_2}$ for some $j_1,k_1,j_2,k_2\in\mathbb{Z}$. I want to show that $x\circ y\in D_n$.
I don't really understand how to do this.
Kindly help me!

Comment: Just use $ba=a^{n-1}b$ to interchange $b$ and $a$ in the middle, and you are done. For another solution, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2613584/show-that-d-n-e-a-a2-an-b-ba-ban-1-be-a-set-of-2n-elements).

Comment: But here we have $b^{k_1}a^{j_2}$ please show. I feel stupid.

Comment: It will help to note that $$ba=a^{n-1}b=a^na^{-1}b=a^{-1}b.$$ Also, to show $D_n$ is a group, you also need to show the existence of an identity, the existence of inverses, and associativity.

Comment: What happens, though, when you multiply $x$ with $y$?

Comment: $xy=a^{j_1}b^{k_1}a^{j_2}b^{k_2}$.

Comment: You can do induction. Try first $xy=a^2bab^2$, say.

Comment: It's going harder for me.

Comment: Observe: $$xy=a^{j_1}\color{red}{(b^{k_1}a^{j_2})}b^{k_2}.$$

Comment: $b^{k_1}$ could be $e, b^{-1}=b$. If $b^{k_1}=e$ we're done. kindly do the next case.

Comment: If $b^{k_1}=b$, then, using $ba=ab^{-1}$, $xy=a^{j_1}(ba^{j_2})b^{k_2}=a^{j_1}(a^{-j_2}b)b^{k_2}=a^{j_1-j_2}b^{k_2+1}$. Is it correct?