# $|\langle a,b \mid a^2=b^2=(ab)^n=1\rangle|\leq 2n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, dihedral-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

I'm trying to prove that group $G=\langle a,b \mid a^2=b^2=(ab)^n=1\rangle\cong D_n$ of order $2n$.

My proof is very similar to the one given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584538/dihedral-group-and-its-generators/1584576#1584576), but I'm struggling to show that $|G|\leq 2n$.

Could you, please, help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a word in $G$ contains some $a^k$ or $b^k$ then $k< 2$. So a word looks like $$bababab \text{ or } ababab \text{ or } abababa \text{ etc}$$

But there could only be $n-1$ times of $ab$ and $n$ times of $ba$ since $(ab)^n=1$.

So how many element can we produce?

EDIT

Since $(ab)^n=1\Rightarrow (ab)^{n-1}=ba,\ (ab)^{n-2}=baba,\ (ab)^{n-3}=bababa$ and so on. So the length of each word can not be bigger than $n$.

For length $1$ we have $2$ words : $a,b$

For length $2$ we have $2$ words : $ab,ba$

For length $3$ we have $2$ words : $aba,bab$

and so on

Hence when we reach length $n$ we have a total of $$2+2+...+2=2n$$ words and it is $2n\leq 2n$

Comment: So we definitely have all $(ab)^k$, where $k<n$. Then we can add $b$ in front and get $b(ab)^k$ or we could add $a$ at the end to get $(ab)^ka$. We can't add both, because it would leave us having $b(ab)^ka=(ab)^{-(k+1)}$ and we already counted this one in. But I can't see how to get $\leq 2n$ evaluation.

Comment: @die Schizophren I have edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

Let $c=ab$. Then $a=cb^{-1}$. The presentation in question is then

$$\langle a,b,c\mid (cb^{-1})^2=b^2=c^n=1, a=cb^{-1}\rangle,$$

which is then, by [Tietze transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_transformations), equivalent to

$$\langle b,c\mid b^2=c^n=1, bcb=c^{-1}\rangle,$$

which is a [standard presentation for $D_n$](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/dihedral.html).

Comment: That's right, thank you, but I'm trying to prove it my way and I have a problem just with one bit